# How to properly flat this Observable array?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I need to flat the results of a Observable<Order[]>[] in a Order[].

The current way that I'm doing it:

```
const ordersObservable: Observable<Order[]>[] = [];
//ordersObservable is populated with a bunch of Observable<Order[]>
forkJoin(ordersObservable)
  .pipe(
    map((results) => ([] as Order[]).concat(...results))
  )
  .subscribe((orders: Order[]) => {
    this.orderService.set(orders);
  //...
  });
```

I've been told that I shouldn't be using `pipe` like that and should be using a RxJs function to handle that.

I've tried to use `concatAll` and `mergeAll` instead of the `map`, but that ended in calling the `orderService` for every item in `ordersObservable`, instead a single time with a flat array with all results of  `ordersObservable`.

What am I doing wrong? And how can I flat the results of all the observables in a single array, preferably with a native RxJs solution?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Pipe IS an RxJs function. https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/pipe

Comment: How are you getting the original Observable? That seems to be the code that would need to be changed to correctly get an `Observable<Order[]>` instead of `Observable<Order[]>[]`.

Comment: AFAIK, it isn't good practice to try to create an array from your Observables? An Observable can emit an array of values, but to create an array of Observables doesn't seem very common or easy to work with.

Comment: @DeborahK imagine that I have a lot of items that need to be on individual requests. Each item is attached to a lot of orders on the backend. This is my Order[].
So on ordersObservable, i put a bunch of requests to the backend, that all need to be managed as one array.

Comment: Could you post what your HTTP call looks like that returns these responses? Maybe we could get it into a better structure at that point instead of after the fact?  Observables aren't like other types of data structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Observable is meant to emit values. With an array of Observables, we need to subscribe to each element of the Observable array to emit the Order array.

I honestly think you should re-evaluate creating an array of Observables. If you want to post another question with the code that is generating that array of Observables, we could provide suggestions.

That said, I *was* able to get something to work. I didn't spend the time to see if there was an *easier* approach.

```
    from(this.ordersObservable)
      .pipe(
        concatAll(),
        scan((acc, value) => [...acc, ...value], [] as Order[]),
        takeLast(1)
      )
      .subscribe((x) => console.log('result', JSON.stringify(x)));
```

First, I needed something to subscribe to. We can't subscribe to the array of Observables. So I used `from` to turn the Array of Observables into another Observable. That way I could subscribe and get the code to execute.

The `from` emits each Observable from the array.

NOTE: `forkJoin` and `combineLatest` also work instead of `from` and provide the same result.

I then use `concatAll()` to concatenate the inner Observables in sequence. It subscribes to each Observable in the array.

`scan` allows us to define an accumulator, accumulating each array of Orders into a single array of orders.

UPDATE: Added `takeLast(1)` to ensure only the last result is emitted.

UPDATE 2: Second option

This also worked and may be a bit simpler:

```
    concat(...this.ordersObservable)
      .pipe(
        scan((acc, value) => [...acc, ...value], [] as Order[]),
        takeLast(1)
      )
      .subscribe((x) => console.log('result', JSON.stringify(x)));
```

This uses array destructuring (the "...") with the `concat` operator to emit all of the values from all of the Observables in the array of Observables. Then we still use `scan` to accumulate them and `takeLast(1)` to emit only once.

I would be interested to know if anyone else is able to simplify this!